# jquery load url content on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application 
In my Index page I have a submenu, when a actionlink is clicked, I want it to call the controller's function via jquery and load all the content and load it in a div.

This is what I have in view

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li onclick="loadDetails">@Html.MenuItemActionSpecific("Details","Details","Account")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItemActionSpecific("Change password", "Manage", "Account")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItemActionSpecific("Connection", "Index", "Connection")</li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

I want to load the content in div `content`

`Html.MenuItemActionSpecific` is custom Html helper.
this is what I tried

```
 function loadDetails() {
        alert("hello");
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load(@Url.Action("Details"));
    }
```

When I click the sub nav menu, the function doesn't get called.

This is the Html generated,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li onclick="loadDetails"><li><a href="/Account/Details">Details</a></li></li>
    <li><li><a href="/Account/Manage">Change password</a></li></li>
    <li><li><a href="/Connection">Connection</a></li></li>
</ul>
```

Details action in controller

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
   ....
    return PartialView(userDetail);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: $('#content').load(@Url.Action("Details")) should that be $('#content').load('@Url.Action("Details")');

Comment: Try `onclick="loadDetails()"`

Comment: @haim770 still doesn't call the function

Comment: That's because you have a lot of other syntax errors.

Comment: @KyorCode still doesn't work. directs me to another page

Comment: @haim770 I also changed `$('#content').load(@Url.Action("Details"));` to `$('#content').load('@Url.Action("Details")');` what other syntax error do I have?

Comment: Well, it's not really a syntax error, but: 1. You're having a nested `li` within `li` (invalid). 2. When you click, you're actually clicking on the second `li` and not the one with the `onclick`.

Comment: Does `loadDetails` function defined globally or within `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below must work.Use this

```
function loadDetails() {
        alert("hello");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('@url.action("Details","YourControllerName")',function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
        })
    }
```

Also in your controller instead of Using `return View("YourViewName")` use return `PartialView("YourViewName");`

Answer (score 0):

Correct errors

Try this

```
<li onclick="loadDetails()"><li><a href="/Account/Details">Details</a></li></li>

$('#content').load('<%= Url.Action("Details") %>');
```

Comment: still directs me to another page(partial view). Doesn't load the content in div

Comment: `$('#content').load('<%= Url.Action("Details") %>');` try this

Comment: Try like this also `$('#content').load('@Url.Content("~/Details")')`

Comment: tried it still directs to another page, I don't know why it is not calling the function. I don't get the alert

Comment: yes `li` will be problem `<li onclick="loadDetails()">Click</li><li><a href="/Account/Details">Details</a></li>` now click the click text

Comment: Yes @Biplov13 Then You mark up is wrong correct it like my code